# mdpi images showing for xhdpi

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-image, android-orientation

I am using an app that has portrait for phone and both portrait and landscape for tablets. However, i recently added a view for splash screen in landscape and both landscape and portrait mode in tablet are pulling mdpi images instead of xhdpi,not sure why this is happening, any clue?
Here's my xml for the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="750dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.36"
        android:paddingLeft="100dp"
        android:paddingRight="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_logo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do the images also exist in the vanilla 'drawable' folder?

Comment: Are you sure the tablet is xhdpi? I would use drawable-sw600dp for tablet only drawables...

Comment: If this isnt a Nexus 10 your tablet is probably hdpi.

Comment: On which tablet are you testing?

Comment: I am using samsung notebook 10, however, i dont have any sw600dp, just xlarge-land and xlarge layout folders under which i am placing the code

Comment: Check out this app to know for sure if the device is indeed xhdpi. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jotabout.screeninfo&hl=en

Comment: @NitinSethi damn you are right, that app indicates, my screen class is xlarge with density mdpi :(, how do i get bigger images to appear with proper resolutions on tablet unlike corresponding smaller images on the phones using mdpi?

Comment: You might try Mikel's suggest. However, I would suggest you to do away with Splash as it does nothing except delaying the time within which user could see something useful for himself. :) It's an anti-pattern which is not recommended in Android.

Comment: It is a requirement in our project, plus we have a lot of other images which are sized differently so might need to work with them :(

Answer (score -1):

Sort of a silly fix but are you positive your tablet is xhdpi? I'm just saying this because a tablet I use to test on is actually ldpi when I just assumed it was xhdpi.

Another thing you can try is creating a new drawable folder drawable-xlarge, which is based on screen size and not pixel density.

Comment: Before I get downvoted to hell, I would write this as a comment but my low rep doesn't let me.

Comment: That's for a reason. It's not an excuse to post it as an answer anyway.